# Adding Node Reference to a Comment

Tags: 7, comments, nodes

If I add a Node Reference field to a node content type (with Reference from URL as a widget,) this field appears in the rendered content and can be used to jump to the referenced node.

I am trying to get a similar result in the rendered comment of the same content type: If I add a Node Reference field with Reference to URL in the Comment Fields edit page of the content type, it doesn't show up in the rendered comment page.

Why do I want to do this? Because when one leaves a comment in the rendered content, a message is sent to the author of the post that a comment was posted. In the email, there is a link to see the comment. The link is of the form *example.com/comment/000#comment-000* and that's not the original post with the comments below.

So I am trying to add a link to the comment page that would send the reader to the rendered node where the comment was originally posted.

Does this mean one cannot reference a node from the same node's comment page?

Or does it mean there is another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to display a node reference in a comment, if your not seeing it show up, I would check ether your fields that are being displayed (at /admin/structure/types/manage/content_type/comment/display) or check your theme to see what's getting printed out.

That being said, if your just looking for a way to put a link in the outbound email to the parent node, there's easier ways to do this. You might want to take a look at [Comment Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_notify), which has a fairly easy to use interface on the back end that allows you to send a template email to the node author that uses [tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) for replacement values.

Another option is to just use [Actions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!actions.inc/group/actions/7), which also uses [tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/token), and add the url to the module. This is handy, as it can be used to send emails to site admins.

Comment: Yes, got it fixed in the theme. I use comment notify, this is how the notification emails are sent. I tried to replace the default token with one that would send the reader directly to the node, but I couldn't find one, so the node reference link appears to be the only solution. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with [Comment Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_notify) module.
We use it on few sites and it works great out of the box.

From module page:

> Features
>
> Mail registered and anonymous users about comment follow-ups
>
> Allow users to unsubscribe from notifications on a specific post with
>   a single click
>
> Allow registered users to preset their follow-up setting in their
>   profile
>
> Users can choose to get notifications about all comments on a node or
>   just replies to their comment
>   Registered authors can get notifications about comments on their nodes
>   Note: Since it only notifies you about published comments, this is not a solution to notify admins when they need to moderate comments on their site

Comment: Interesting approach. I am going to look into it. Thanks. :)